# Arcs/vertices to MultiPolygon

Tags: c#, sql-server, gis, geojson

I have a list of Arcs (vertices) in this form:

```
public class Arc
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public double X1 { get; set; }
    public double Y1 { get; set; }
    public double X2 { get; set; }
    public double Y2 { get; set; }
}
```

which I can serialize into a [MultiLineString GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#id6) like this in the case of 2 Arcs:

```
{ "type": "MultiLineString",
    "coordinates": [
    [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0] ],
    [ [102.0, 2.0], [103.0, 3.0] ]
    ]
}
```

My underlying data actually represent Polygons. More precisely a [MultiPolygon](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#id7):

```
{ "type": "MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [[[102.0, 2.0], [103.0, 2.0], [103.0, 3.0], [102.0, 3.0], [102.0, 2.0]]],
      [[[100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0]],
       [[100.2, 0.2], [100.8, 0.2], [100.8, 0.8], [100.2, 0.8], [100.2, 0.2]]]
      ]
    }
```

Just curious, is it possible to transform the original Arcs into a MultiPolygon? I am also thinking about doing it via SQL Server's GIS functionalities. Did anyone ever encounter a similar problem? Any pointers would be very much appreciated. Many thanks.

PS:

The arcs are currently disjoint and when combined should form a closed polygon. The following picture shows a part of a potential polygon.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're have pairs of opposite corners for some squares and you want to get the actual squares. Is that right?

Comment: The first part is correct, I have opposite corners for some squares. However, they do not necessarily represent complete squares but just the currently disjoint outer borders. I have added a picture to illustrate this.

Comment: Ah. So if I can read into the other questions that you've been asking lately, your trying to tessellate a larger area with squares (that you'll union together).

Comment: Yes. I tried to union but this did not scale so I came up with an approach that finds the outer 'arcs' or outer most vertices of the 'union-ed' squares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. I present this with the huge caveat that I wrote it very iteratively and if I came across this from someone else in production code, I'd have a talk with them. :)

```
declare @g geography = geography::STGeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((100 0, 101 1), (102 2, 103 3))', 4236);
declare @multiPoly geography;

with cte as (
    select *
    from dbo.Numbers as n
    cross apply (
        select *
        from (values 
            (@g.STGeometryN(number).STStartPoint().Lat, @g.STGeometryN(number).STStartPoint().Long, 1),
            (@g.STGeometryN(number).STEndPoint().Lat, @g.STGeometryN(number).STStartPoint().Long, 2),
            (@g.STGeometryN(number).STEndPoint().Lat, @g.STGeometryN(number).STEndPoint().Long, 3),
            (@g.STGeometryN(number).STStartPoint().Lat, @g.STGeometryN(number).STEndPoint().Long, 4),
            (@g.STGeometryN(number).STStartPoint().Lat, @g.STGeometryN(number).STStartPoint().Long, 5)
        ) as x(Lat, Long, n)
    ) as decomp
    where n.Number <= @g.STNumGeometries()
)
select @multiPoly = geography::STGeomFromText(
    'MULTIPOLYGON (' + stuff((
        select ', ((' + stuff((
            select ', ' + cast(cte.Long as varchar(10)) + ' ' + cast(cte.Lat as varchar(10))
            from cte
            where Number = n.Number
            order by cte.n
            for xml path('')
        ), 1, 2, '') + '))'
        from dbo.Numbers as n
        where n.Number <= @g.STNumGeometries()
        for xml path('')
        ), 1, 2, '') + ')'
    , 4236);


select @multiPoly;
```

Comment: Thanks for that, will check it. TSQL - even better ... would never have thought that you can achieve this 'set based'.

Comment: Sorry what is dbo.Numbers.

Comment: It's what's called a tally table. Literally a table of one column each row of which is a number 1 out larger.

Comment: Ah OK, I have actually used something similar in the past. To clarify, this is what you mean: http://dwaincsql.com/2014/03/27/tally-tables-in-t-sql/